# how is current measured through ammeter?

Tags: magnetic-fields

If we join a shunt through a galvanometer,it makes an ammeter.but in parallel arrangement voltage is same and only some amount of current is passed and not the total current of circuit.so how does the ammeter gives the value of total current in circuit????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conversion of Moving coil galvanometer to ammeter](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/100274/)

Answer (score 1):

As you said in shunt the galvanometer is connected in series, this makes it an ammeter, An ammeter has very minimal resistance (ideally zero), So it lets all the current pass through it, causing very minimal (ideally zero) voltage drop across it